# Javascript - using sessionStorage vs variables

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an Ext-JS(Sencha) mobile application. After a user logs in, i load some data from the server in which I store in  variables for the users session.
I was wondering if it was better to use sessionStorage vs putting these into variables, or if it even made a difference. (The data is sometimes pretty large, but it's not static enough to put into localStorage).

Are there any advantages to using sessionStorage, from a performance standpoint, over in-memory variables ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I would say the advantage is that session storage will go across page loads. If the data is not going to outlast a page load just use variables.

Answer (score 2):

It really comes down to: a **single value** vs. **JSON**. Unless you're stashing your data really deeply in JSON and require looping to get to it, there is no real performance difference.

JSON is more convenient in that you have save the session data in one go, rather than have to iterate over separate variables.

Comment: There is a way to store JSON values in `sessionStorage` too. `sessionStorage['key']=JSON.strigify(jsonObject);`
Retrieving
`var jsonObject=JSON.parse(sessionStorage['key']);`

But if you need to frequently perform `parse` and `strigify` operations you will have to look out for performance.